# Error Fetching the Json data

Tags: android, json

Hi this my json data

```
{"CategoryID":1,"CategoryName":"Clothing","Status":true,"SubCategoryList":    [{"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":1,"SubCategoryName":"Male"},    {"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":2,"SubCategoryName":"Female"},    {"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":3,"SubCategoryName":"Kids"},    {"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":4,"SubCategoryName":"New Born Baby"},    {"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":11,"SubCategoryName":"Sun Glasses"}]},    {"CategoryID":2,"CategoryName":"Alcohol","Status":true,"SubCategoryList":    [{"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":5,"SubCategoryName":"Wine"},    {"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":6,"SubCategoryName":"Beer"},    {"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":7,"SubCategoryName":"Scotch"}]},    {"CategoryID":3,"CategoryName":"Restourents","Status":false,"SubCategoryList":   [{"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":8,"SubCategoryName":"Breakfast"},   {"Status":true,"SubCategoryID":9,"SubCategoryName":"Tour Package"}]}]
```

My Code :

```
JSONArray collection = new JSONArray(json1);
int length = collection.length();
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
JSONObject row = collection.getJSONObject(i);
String value = row.getString("CategoryName");
String value6 = row.getString("SubCategoryName");
}
```

Got the values for CategoryName: Clothing, Alcohol, Restourents.
unable to get the value for SubCategoryName.
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for SubCategoryName
How to get data for SubCategoryName.

Answer (score 0):

`SubCategoryName` is inside SubCategoryList jsonArray

```
JsonArray arr = row.getJsonArray("SubCategoryList");
arr.getJsonObject[0].getString("SubCategoryName");
```